# Sqlcmd Error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I create a bat file for the first time, and have the following issue: my command is running just fine when I type it directly into the command prompt, but it's not running through the bat file I created. The script is:

```
@echo off
sqlcmd -S DESKTOP-55JKCD5\SQLEXPRESS -i “C:\Users\Didi\Documents\SQL\test.sql” -o “C:\Users\Didi\Documents\SQL\output.csv” -s”,”
```

I get the following message from cmd:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file ôC:\Users\Didi\Documents\SQL\test.sqlö (Reason: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect).

I can't understand what's wrong, provided that I don't have any issues when typing directly in cmd.

I'm begging for your advice, guys! Bat files are totally new for me, apologies is asking a stupid question.

Comment: Looks like you are using typographic quotes instead of normal ones. Are you using MSWord/Libre-/Openoffice as editor?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue...command prompt isn't liking when I try to run the following statement: sqlcmd -SXXXXXXXX14XX,14XX\SESDMINT -E -dmaster -iD:\SFAS\SSIS\SESDatamart\ddl\"StageTable - QIPSRevenueRecalcValues.sql" -v dbName=SESDMInt ddlPath="D:\SFAS\SSIS\SESDatamart\ddl" .  I've tried copying from Notepad++ to ensure the quotes come across okay, but no luck....any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use "smart quotes"! Use `"` - in a proper editor, not a word-processor.

Comment: Yes, the issue was in the quotes, now I used another ones and all is working properly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this exe from Azure Dev Ops you can also get this issue if there is a new line in the definition of the step in the Release or Pipeline. The step is multiline so it is difficult to spot. It's the difference between:

```
ServerRoleMembership;ServerRoles;RoleMembership;Permissions" /v:Environment=$(Environment) /Diagnostics:true
 /p:ScriptDatabaseOptions=false
```

and

```
 ServerRoleMembership;ServerRoles;RoleMembership;Permissions" /v:Environment=$(Environment) /Diagnostics:true /p:ScriptDatabaseOptions=false
```

Both look same in Dev Ops, it's only when you copy them out to notepad you will see the new line